# Backing up an Oracle 10G Express on Windows 2000 Server

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-10g

**Oracle 10G Express installed on Windows 2000 Server Enterprise Edition.**

I am trying to automate backups and on Oracle's website I have found the following documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/backrest.htm

**Activate Archive Log**

1. SQLPLUS -> CONNECT SYS/password AS SYSDBA
2. SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
3. STARTUP MOUNT
4. ALTER DATABASE ARCHIVELOG;
5. ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

**Backup the Database**

Then using the backup.bat file provided by Oracle: **D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\BACKUP.BAT**, I can backup the database either manually or with Scheduled tasks

Using a test server, I have been able to backup and restore the database using the backup.bat and restore.bat files provided.  I have not seen anything however about recycling those backups.

**Questions:**

1. Does Oracle provide a script to cleanup backup files that are no longer needed?
   or What can I do to avoid filling up the D: drive with backup files?
2. Is there a better method to backup Oracle 10G Express?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the 10g version of Express Edition installed, but if it is like the 11g version, then your first question is answered in the comments section of the Backup.bat file itself.

For 11g this means the comments indicate that No cleanup script is needed because the script automatically keeps two backups in the Flash Recovery Area.  Whether there is a better method or not will depend on what your recovery requirements are.

Comment: Thank you Leigh, is this the comment you are referring to? REM Two backups are maintained in Flash Recovery Area

Comment: Yes, that is what is says in the 11g version.

Comment: Thank you, so for my first question, is this the common/accepted method for backuping up an Oracle Express?

Comment: Yes, in fact looking at the backup scripts the batch file is running, the same script could work just fine for a Standard or even Enterprise Edition backup.  Oracle really does make some powerful tools available in their free XE version.